# How to format this txt file using Regex

Tags: regex

Have a `.txt` file with data folded up into a single column, looking to turn it into a `.csv` so I can import it into a DB table.

Source file:

```
1000
AAAAAAAAAA
100,000.00
2000
BBBBBBBBBB
200,000.00
3000
CCCCCCCCCC
300,000.00
4000
DDDDDDDDDD
400,000.00
```

Looking to turn it into:

```
1000,AAAAAAAAA,100,000.00
2000,BBBBBBBBB,200,000.00
3000,CCCCCCCCC,300,000.00
4000,DDDDDDDDD,400,000.00
```

I've tried this so far and am stuck there:

```
find  -       ^(\d+)(\s)
substitue -   $1,
```

That gets me this output:

```
1000,AAAAAAAAA
100,000.00
2000,BBBBBBBBB
200,000.00
3000,CCCCCCCCC
300,000.00
4000,DDDDDDDDD
400,000.00
```

Would love any pointers to move ahead.

Thanks,
CH

Comment: Something isn't right here, because on most databases you should already be able to import this file, using space character as the separator for columns.  What is your database?

Comment: I'm using an ORCL db right now, I can go MySQL / MSSQL either way is fine. Maybe my approach is wrong, I'd figured I couldn't import it into db, because each row is folded up over 3 rows, how to unpivot it back is sort of my issue I guess.

Comment: I mispoke because your original data was not formatted properly.

Comment: oh sorry, I noticed that my formatting hadn't carried over and had to redo it. apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following find and replace:

```
Find:    (.*)\r?\n(.*)\r?\n(.*)(?:\r?\n|$)
Replace: $1|$2|$3\n
```

This approach captures each of three successive lines, and then concatenates together into a single line using pipe as the separator.  Note carefully that it is *not* acceptable to use comma as a separator here, because some of your numeric data already uses comma.

Follow the link below for a running demo.

### Demo

Comment: Ha ha !! you beaut !! Thank you so much, beautiful.

Comment: I left out the step where you tell your DB loader tool to use `|` as the separator, but I think you can figure out the rest :-)

Comment: Ha yea, I figured that one as soon as I saw the pipe.

Comment: I got the line data formatted perfectly using your code [Pipe Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NpoqDI/1), have this header data at the top that another user helped me format [Header Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YvEH5t/2), how can I apply this second formatting to only the first 7 rows, that way the entire txt file is the exact no. of columns and pipe delimited.

Comment: Regex alone can't easily do this.  I would use an application language such as Java, C#, Python or maybe Perl.  That being said, 7 lines is few enough that you could probably wing it and do it by hand if you needed to.

Comment: Ahh thanks ! I was afraid of that. Glad you confirmed. I'll try a different approach, handle it outside somehow. Appreciate the assist.

Comment: It is not true that the separator must always be a character not used in the data. There are some cases when that's not possible (if the data is not known in advance). That is why there are escaping mechanisms - for example, tokens may be enclosed in double-quotes and separated by comma (and the import mechanisms of Oracle and other databases are fully aware and capable of handling such data encoding). Of course, what you did here is much **simpler** than that, but it relies on knowing beforehand that pipe doesn't also appear in the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

If every a row consists of 3 items, maybe try splitting the txt file based on spaces and then writing to a csv file?

For example in python:

```
result = []

def writeToCSV(result):
with open('new.csv', 'a') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        writer.writerow(result)

with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

ind = 0
for row in spamreader:
    result.append(row)
    ind += 1
    if(ind == 3):
        ind = 0
        writeToCSV(result)
        result = []
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I will try this one out as well !! appreciate the detailed response !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\d+)\n(\w+)\n([\d,.]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/VGkCzJ/2)**

With this replacement string:

```
$1,$2,$3
```

Comment: Thank you Federico !! Works like a charm. I'll keep this one around as well. Appreciate it.

Comment: On Windows the line ending might be `\r\n`.